# WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_yield$Location$getLa.coords')

Tags: react-native, expo

[enter image description [image]here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdRWP.png)

Comment: Hi! Did you solved the issue? I have the same Error as you :(

Comment: No. If you have solved the error please help me out too...